# How does CronJobs understand that the first word is user or command?

Tags: linux, cron

When we write in the `cronjobs` file:

```
* * * * * foo bar
```

How does the system know that `foo` is a user that you need to execute the `bar` command, or that `foo` is a command for which `bar` is an input parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinction is made between the *user* crontab file, in which case there is no username field, and the *system* crontab file(s) where there is always a username. *user* crontab files are those accessed via the `crontab(1)` command. *system* crontab files instead typically reside under an `etc` directory and are not edited through the `crontab(1)` interface.

Therefore `cron(8)` or `crond(8)` merely needs to know whether a *user* crontab file is being parsed (sixth field is a command) or a *system* file (sixth field is a username and maybe also a group). This can be set via a flag depending on which directory the cron file is being run from. Meanwhile, the system administrator can hopefully remember whether they are editing a file via `crontab -e` for some *user* or instead editing a *system* crontab file.

Comments are typical in the file as reminder of the fields e.g. the default *user* crontab file for `root` on OpenBSD contains:

```
#minute hour    mday    month   wday    [flags] command
...
```

or in a *system* crontab file from some Linux system one may find a comment along the lines of:

```
#minute hour    mday    month   wday    user    command

# how much are the dhcp pools being used?
36      */4     *       *       *       root    ...
```

Reading through `crontab(5)` from time to time is a good idea, as there are some other gotchas you may want to remind yourself about.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on which crontab file you are editing.

Per-user crontab files do not have a user field because it's clear which user account will be executing the command. On the other hand an entry in the system crontab file(s) needs a field to identify the user account under which the command is to be run